# How to create an outline mat-checkbox

Tags: css, angular, checkbox, sass, angular-material

How to invert the colors of a mat-checkbox so that the border and check mark are colored and the rest transparent?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Creating a global style for a given class (**outline**) and adding that class to the mat-checkbox.

**src/style.scss**

```
@import '~@angular/material/theming';
@include mat-core();
$app-primary: mat-palette($mat-indigo);
$app-accent:  mat-palette($mat-pink, A200, A100, A400);
$app-warn: mat-palette($mat-red);
$theme: mat-light-theme($app-primary, $app-accent);
@include angular-material-theme($theme);
$primary: mat-color($app-primary);
$accent: mat-color($app-accent);
$warn: mat-color($app-warn);

@mixin checkbox-color($color) {
  .mat-checkbox-frame {
      border-color: $color;
    }
    &.mat-checkbox-checked .mat-checkbox-checkmark-path {
      stroke: $color !important;
    }
}
mat-checkbox.mat-checkbox.outline {
  .mat-checkbox-background {
    background-color: transparent;
  }
  &.mat-primary {
    @include checkbox-color($primary);
  }
  &.mat-warn {
    @include checkbox-color($warn)
  }
  &.mat-accent {
     @include checkbox-color($accent)
  }
}
```

`<mat-checkbox class="outline" color="primary"></mat-checkbox>`

[Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-k9rhvf?embed=1&file=src/styles.scss)